# Selecting specific rows in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot, m

Iam new to Power query and are currently trying to find a solution to a problem.I have a table like below, where same emp.nos have same rank

```
Dense_rank |emp.no |Type
------------------------------------
     1     | 0034  |Employee_active
     1     | 0034  |Inactive
     2     | 0056  |Employee_active
     2     | 0056  |Employee_active
     3     | 0062  |Employee_active
     3     | 0062  |Employee_active
     4     | 0077  |Employee_active
     4     | 0077  |Inactive
```

So basically I want to select the duplicate rows where both duplicates have 'Employee_active' against them. The context is, if there are multiple employee records where all are active, then that needs to be flagged. If one record is 'Employee_active' and its duplicate is 'Inactive', then it is fine. So I want to filter and the resulting table should look like below:

```
Dense_Rank|emp.no|Type
----------------------------------
2         |0056  |Employee_active
2         |0056  |Employee_active
3         |0062  |Employee_active
3         |0062  |Employee_active
```

I can write an logical query to create a calculated column if the values to check for was in same row but since it is in different rows I am a bit lost

Comment: Will there ever be more than two rows per employee?  And can there be any other entries than the two you mention?

Comment: Yes there could be 3 or 4 duplicates, however the 2 entries will be the Only two (Employee_active and Inactive) in the type column

Comment: If there are four duplicates, and three of them are `Employee_active` and one is `Inactive`, what kind of a result would you want?  Is it also true that if there are no duplicates (i.e just a single row); than that row should not be returned.  What if both are Inactive?

Comment: If more than one(duplicate) record has 'Employee_Active' against them then those rows must be returned.If there are no duplicates then I do not need them, But all of these records have duplicates as I grouped them first,added the dense_Rank column and filtered it to records with more than 1 count

Comment: Is this restatement of the question equivalent to what you want? "Remove employees that have an `Inactive` type in their rows." If not, why not?

Comment: If Both are employee_active then I want it,(as this mean there are 2 active employee records under same employee number).if one is employee_active and other is Inactive then I do not want it

Answer (score 1):

Starting with your table as `Source`, you can

- group by ID with no aggregation
- Add a custom column

  ```
  if 
       List.Count(List.FindText(Table.Column([Grouped],"Type"), "Employee_active")) > 1
       then [Grouped] else null
  ```

*Note that this returns all rows for the employee if there is more than one row containing `Employee_active`. If you want to return only those rows in the duplicates that contain "Employee_active", a different formula can do that.*

- Expand the custom column
- Filter out the nulls and remove the extra column
- rearrange the columns.

You could probably initiate this algorithm even before you create your duplicate table which I am using as Source.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Dense_rank", Int64.Type}, {"emp.no", type text}, {"Type", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"emp.no"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Dense_rank=nullable number, emp.no=nullable text, Type=nullable text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each if 
            List.Count(List.FindText(Table.Column([Grouped],"Type"), "Employee_active")) > 1
            then [Grouped] else null),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Dense_rank", "Type"}, {"Dense_rank", "Type"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"Grouped"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each ([Type] = "Employee_active")),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Dense_rank", "emp.no", "Type"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]